# How to pass PHP array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send an array via $.ajax to a PHP Script.

```
<?php
$arrid=array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
?>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: 'paidmail.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: 'id=<?php print_r($arrid); ?>',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
</script>
```

paidmail.php just echo out the id.
But my Console always throws this Exception:

```
unterminated string literal
```

How is it possible to send an array via $.ajax to another PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r()` returns a string, which will contain Javascript meta characters, particularly the single quote `'`, which will cause syntax errors. Instead of print_r, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode), which will transform a PHP array into a syntactically valid Javascript data structure.

```
  data: 'id=<?php echo json_encode($arrid); ?>',
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
data: 'id=<?php print_r($arrid); ?>'
```

with:

```
data: {id: <?php echo json_encode($arrid);?>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc, don't you also want to utf-8 encode?

```
data: 'id=<?php echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode' , $arrid)); ?>',
```

And you should probably also use POST instead of GET:

```
type: "POST"
```